# pushing vite reactjs build on GitHub pages gives 404 on build files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages, vite

i have a reactjs website using vitejs when i compile it using `npm run build` it generates the compiled site inside dist folder, when i publish the content to this folder i encounter a

> Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.

and serval

> GET https://brijrajparmar27.github.io/assets/index.d12487b2.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

here what i find odd is that if you check the url in above error its trying to find the .js file inside `brijrajparmar27.github.io/assets/` shouldn't it be inside `https://brijrajparmar27.github.io/[Repo-Name]/assets`?

it still works on my localhost though somehow.

after looking at this i added the `[Repo-name]/` manually at the beginning of link tags of compiled index.html file in dist folder, on hosting that i got

> GET https://brijrajparmar27.github.io/Atmosphere/Atmosphere/assets/vendor.95b2f1d7.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

repo name is listed twice.

Comment: I'm getting this issue too, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that `vite build` defaults base to single "/" https://vitejs.dev/config/#base

I've fixed issue with incorrect request URL by changing build script in package.json to:

`"build": "vite build --base=./"`